# « Prévu en » ou « prévu pour » ?

Tags: prépositions

Quelle préposition doit-on utiliser pour introduire un complément de temps après le verbe *prévoir*?

> Le prochain passage de la comète est prévu pour novembre 2015.

ou

> Le prochain passage de la comète est prévu en novembre 2015.

Sur le site du *Bureau de la traduction (Termium)* se trouve [une réponse](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_autr84vWAiHFbX6w&page=9dmBsucRcXHQ.html) à cette même question selon laquelle l'usage de *pour* est classique. Cependant, l'usage de *en* est en train de gagner du terrain dans le langage courant car *en* se compose naturellement avec les noms du mois dans d'autres tournures. Cette réponse laisse la porte ouverte à l'usage des deux prépositions.

En France, est-ce qu'il y a une règle qui régit ce cas ? Ou bien c'est « à l'oreille » (auquel cas *en* paraît plus naturel) ?

Comment: Piste à vérifier ou invalider : j'entrevois une nuance entre les deux termes. On prévoit _pour_ une date (c'est prévu pour le 11 novembre 2015). Ceci ne fonctionne pas avec _en_. J'aurais tendance à dire que _pour_ est à privilégier lorsque la date est précise, _en_ lorsqu'elle s'inscrit dans une fourchette. Ceci est contre-intuitif : dans certains cas, le mois est la date précise. Si j'ai su la date mais que j'ai oublié le jour précis, j'utiliserai _en_ (« c'est prévu en novembre, j'ai oublié la date exacte. »).

Comment: j'aurais dis, mais sans source: prévu pour une date, prévu en un pays, prévu a une ville. avec des règles d'adaptation (on dit pas "les J.O. sont prévu en Brésil", ni "... prévu à Arles").

Comment: @Archemar, À Arles, on dit très justement « à Arles ». C'est à Arras, à Amiens, à Alfortville mais surtout à Paris qu'on dit parfois le toléré « .. en Arles » ;-)

Comment: @Archemar «  Les J.O. *du* Brésil sont prévus *en* août 2016 »  ; « Les J.O. 2016 sont prévus *au* Brésil *au* mois d'août »

Comment: @cl-r : l'exemple des J.O. semble intéressant. Quelle serait la différence de sens entre "Les J.O. du Brésil sont prévus en août 2016" et "Les J.O du Brésil sont prévus pour août 2016" ? Puisque les J.O sont programmés, j'aurais tendance à utiliser *pour* en suivant les conseils dans votre réponse mais *en* sonne plus naturel. Où est-ce que je me trompe ?

Comment: @user137846 - J'ai compléter ma réponse pour essayer de clarifier ma réponse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L'[article](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_autr84vWAiHFbX6w&page=9dmBsucRcXHQ.html) auquel on réfère présente tout d'abord une traduction du *Guide anglais-français de la traduction* (R. Meertens) où on rend *the elections scheduled for March*<sup>1</sup> par *les élections prévues en mars* (il faut noter qu'on a l'expression *déclencher des élections* par opposition au moment de la tenue du scrutin, le moment des élections). Mais le choix de la préposition participe de l’ambiguïté dont on traite à la fin de l'article mais qu'on ne signale pas d'entrée de jeu pour ce premier exemple.

---

Dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, *ed. Duculot*), au  §315c, on donne un exemple qui illustre ce genre d'ambiguïté, quoiqu'avec un verbe différent :

> *Je les ai invités ce matin pour demain soir.* (*LBU*)
>
> ---
>
> Je les ai invités [pour](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pour) demain soir.
>   *Je les ai invités [en](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en) matinée. [ambigu]
>   *Je les ai invités en matinée en après-midi. [incohérent]
>   *Je les ai invités ce matin en après-midi. [incohérent]

Ici, quand on omet le premier complément (moment de l'invitation), on conserve la préposition avec le deuxième pour indiquer qu'il réfère au moment où la rencontre aura lieu. Dans cet exemple seule la préposition *pour* n'introduit aucune ambiguïté pour désigner le moment où elle se tiendra. En effet, on a le moment où l'invitation est faite (*ce matin*), mais surtout le moment de la rencontre (*demain soir*), évidemment un moment futur.

Avec *en* on s'appuie sur le contexte pour atténuer l'ambiguïté : on sait par exemple qu'on ne perd pas de temps à nous parler du moment où l'on formule une prédiction/invitation ; on identifie la source et on parle surtout du moment où l'*évènement* va se produire et de l'évènement lui-même. On peut aussi avoir différents énoncés qui précèdent, avec des indications de temps ou des notions (comme *déclencher des élections*) qui peuvent préciser le contexte. Mais l'emploi avec *en* seul impliquerait avec *inviter* qu'il puisse amorcer un deuxième complément quand le premier serait omis, et qu'il puisse établir clairement le sens du moment où l'évènement annoncé se produit. Avec deux compléments débutant par *en*, il manquerait un verbe non équivoque pour orienter le deuxième complément avec le verbe présenté en question (par exemple : *la rencontre (qui est) prévue ce matin aura lieu en après-midi* / *est reportée à cet après-midi*). L'ambiguïté subsisterait mais serait pour ainsi dire neutralisée, sauf que ce n'est plus un seul et même verbe (voir aussi *prévoir + que*).

---

La manière de cibler un moment le plus précisément avec une préposition implique sans doute d'utiliser *à* ou un déterminant et une date (*prévoir la date des éclipses*, TLFi), plutôt que les idées associées à pour (*vers*) et en (*contenu* d'un mois). Même si ces prépositions peuvent<sup>2</sup> rendre un moment précis dans le temps, l'évènement se déroulera à une date précise. Mais avec [*prévoir*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9voir) on n'est pas plus capable à mon avis de réaliser sans ambiguïté le moment où doit se concrétiser la prédiction, avec un complément en *à* qu'avec un complément construit avec *en* :

> *Le prochain passage de la comète est prévu au mois de septembre 2015. [ambigu]
>   *Le prochain passage de la comète n'est prévu qu'en septembre 2015. [ambigu]

À mon avis l'ambiguïté persiste, et on pourrait ajouter aux deux exemples *pour janvier 2016* et ainsi détrôner le complément débutant par *au* ou *en*.

---

La construction avec *en* qu'on a présenté avec le verbe prévoir m'apparaît ambiguë et si l'on devait l'utiliser avec un premier complément de temps, on utilisera *pour* avec le deuxième. La préposition *pour* semble au final, à mon avis, la seule qui soit apte à générer systématiquement *ici* l'idée de la fin du terme de la prédiction, s’achevant à la faveur du moment où celle-ci se concrétise (ou non).

Quant à l'affirmation selon laquelle la préposition *en* est plus fréquente avec les noms de mois, on aurait aimé en savoir davantage (on cite un extrait du *Devoir*, un autre de *Radio-Canada* et un au *Figaro*). À mon avis *en mars*, c'est simplement *au mois de mars*. Je n'interprète pas les résultats au corpus *Google* mais on peut jeter un coup d’œil ([1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=est%20pr%C3%A9vu%20*%2Cest%20pr%C3%A9vu%20*_ADP&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cest%20pr%C3%A9vu%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20pour%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20par%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20dans%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20au%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20d%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cest%20pr%C3%A9vu%20*_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20pour_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20par_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20%C3%A0_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20dans_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20de_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20au_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20en_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20d%27_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20des_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vu%20aux_ADP%3B%2Cc0), [2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pourvoir%20*_ADP%2Cpourvu%20*_ADP&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cpourvoir%20*_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpourvoir%20%C3%A0_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvoir%20aux_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvoir%20par_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvoir%20au_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvoir%20en_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvoir%20contre_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvoir%20de_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvoir%20pour_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvoir%20devant_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvoir%20dans_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cpourvu%20*_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpourvu%20de_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvu%20%C3%A0_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvu%20par_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvu%20d%27_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvu%20en_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvu%20au_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvu%20aux_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvu%20du_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvu%20d_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourvu%20dans_ADP%3B%2Cc0), [3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pr%C3%A9vue%20pour%20novembre%2Cpr%C3%A9vue%20en%20novembre%2Cpr%C3%A9vue%20pour%20janvier%2Cpr%C3%A9vue%20en%20janvier%2Cest%20pr%C3%A9vue%20*_ADP&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%A9vue%20pour%20novembre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%A9vue%20en%20novembre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%A9vue%20pour%20janvier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%A9vue%20en%20janvier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cest%20pr%C3%A9vue%20*_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vue%20pour_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vue%20par_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vue%20%C3%A0_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vue%20dans_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vue%20en_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vue%20au_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vue%20sur_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vue%20aux_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vue%20de_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Best%20pr%C3%A9vue%20avec_ADP%3B%2Cc0)) sur les prépositions avec *prévoir*.

---

<sub>1. C'est hors sujet, mais en anglais il est 100% clair que *scheduled for+moment* réfère au moment de réalisation de l'objet de la planification. On a aussi des nuances : *the meeting was scheduled this morning for later this afternoon* ; *the meeting we scheduled in the/this morning for later this afternoon will be held on Friday instead* etc.</sub>

<sub>2. Il y a des exemples d'affinités particulières de prépositions avec certains verbes/compléments, comme dans le cas du verbe [*partir*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3904), alors qu'on dit *je pars en vacances* (*en* est souvent utilisée avec plusieurs expressions figées) mais *je pars pour un long voyage* quand il est déterminé. Et c'est avec ce verbe qu'on a critiqué les emplois d'autres prépositions que *pour* pour réaliser la destination, depuis qu'ils sont apparus au 18<sup>e</sup>. Avec *partir*, on utilise *pour* afin d'indiquer le terme de l'absence, et non pas *pendant* qui signifierait la durée du départ. D'autres [phénomènes](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/15958) impliquent par exemple un verbe utilisé comme [*factitif*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factitif), comme lorsqu'on oppose *éviter quelque chose ou quelqu'un* à *éviter quelque chose à quelqu'un.* On part d'un sujet grammatical qui réalise l'action du verbe pour glisser vers une construction avec un complément indirect qui devient en fait celui qui va réaliser l'action d'*éviter*. On utilise souvent la préposition *à* dans de tels cas.</sub>

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Pourriez-vous m'expliquer pourquoi selon vous les deux phrases encadrées sont-elles ambiguës ?

Comment: @user137846 Je vous en prie. Je dirais premièrement parce qu'elles peuvent toutes deux dire qu'on a fait la prévision (l'action de faire un pronostic) en septembre et qu'on n'a pas encore parlé ou indiqué la date à laquelle la comète doit passer. C'est le sens de détrôner avec _pour_ par la suite : _Le prochain passage de la comète est prévu au mois de septembre 2015, pour janvier 2016_. Ce ne sont pas tous les verbes qui ont cette double nature du moment du verbe par opposition au moment du procès etc. Il y a aussi les considérations de précision, comme avec le _rendez-vous_. Merci.

Answer (score 2):

- *Prévoir pour* a pour synonyme *programmer*.

En fait on prévoit quelque chose pour que cela fonctionne, le mois durant lequel le fonctionnement sera avéré est 'secondaire' par rapport à l'action engagée :

> La livraison est *prévue pour* novembre 2015 (plus ou moins les aléas de fabrication).

- Prévoir, avec pour synonyme *anticiper, pressentir, pronostiquer* s’accommode plus facilement de *en*, il est nécessaire pour le futur :

> - Quand cela se réalisera-t-il ?
>  - *En* février 2016.

Donc « Le passage de la comète est prévu *en* novembre 2015 [les calculs sont formels : précisément son périgée sera le ../../..] » est plus conforme, mais le *pour* peut être entendu ; alors qu'on ne pourrait pas dire « La comète passera pour novembre », novembre n'étant pas une entité pour laquelle on peut faire quelque chose.

---

*Complément suite aux commentaires*

Il y a seulement un changement de point de vue :

- *pour* se réfère au J.O. qui auront lieu *en*, donc si vous parler des J.O., de leur organisation, des lieux, des personnes ... tout est prévu *pour*  `[`fonctionner *en* `]`  août, et naturellement on supprime ce qu'il y a entre les `[]` pour ne pas 'alourdir' la phrase.
- Mais si vous voulez vous rendre aux J.O., c'est *en* août que cela se passera, donc de votre point de vue *en* est préférable, car vous précisez seulement *le nom* d'une période qui s'appelait *[Thermidor](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendrier_r%C3%A9publicain)* pendant la révolution ...

Cela se complique si vous faites des phrases avec *de* ajouté à *en* ou à *pour*:

- ... si vous préciser *la période* : J'ai prévu de partir au J.O. *au* mois *d'* août. (*En* et *pour* ne fonctionnent pas ici, mais vous avez ajouté *d'* entre *août* et *prévu* ).
- J'ai prévu *de* prendre les billets *pour* août. Vous les prenez maintenant pour une période future.
- J'ai prévu *de* prendre les billets *en* août. Vous les achèterez plus tard, dans le futur.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse ! J'ai deux questions : (i) "... est plus conforme,...". Est-ce que la conformité est à l'usage actuel ou aux règles ? (ii) L'utilisation d'un à la place de l'autre, peut-il prêter à confusion ?

Comment: @user137846  (i) "... est plus conforme,..." à l'accord sur le temps : il s'est passé quelque chose *en* 1789 (la révolution française, l'emploi de *pour* est une faute), il se passera quelque chose *en* 2017 (élection présidentielle, mais les candidats se préparent *pour* 2017). On ne peut pas utiliser *pour* lorsque l'on fait référence à temps passé ou futur, mais s'il à quelque chose de prévu, *pour* se rattache à cette 'chose' : le lancement est *pour* (ou *en*) janvier 2016, mais l'inauguration aura lien *en* janvier 2016.